In Typescript, can I use an Interface or Type to reject bad input data?
I want to load in some text from a CSV file with 3 fields: The AWS resource name, the AWS resource type, and an action. The resource name can be any ARN, and the resource type is one of "load_balancer", "ecs_cluster", or "lambda_function". The action can be one of REMOVE or ADD. Each CSV line is called a ResourceEntry in this post. I'm not sure of the correct terminology to use, I am very new to Typescript.
When reading in the records from CSV, I'd like to reject invalid records, for instance an unknown action, or a resource type that isn't listed above. Can I accomplish that with an Interface defining the ResourceEntry type?
Here's what I'm doing right now:
// also has a 'class IterableResourceEntry implements ResourceEntry {'
interface ResourceEntry {
  resource_name: string;
  resource_type: ResourceType;
  action: ActionType;
}

interface ActionType {
  type: 'REMOVE' | 'ADD';
}

interface ResourceType {
  type: 'load_balancer' | 'ecs_cluster' | 'lambda_function';
}

Is it possible to use those definitions to validate each record?

No, typescript's types only exist at compile time. To check data at runtime, you will need code, not types. You could either write the code yourself, or use a library like zod

Yes, you can have a function that checks if a given value is a ResourceEntry (although your definitions of ActionType and ResourceType are slightly off.
const actionTypes = ['REMOVE', 'ADD'] as const;
const resourceTypes = ['load_balancer', 'ecs_cluster', 'lambda_function'] as const;

type ActionType = typeof actionTypes[number];
type ResourceType = typeof resourceTypes[number];

interface ResourceEntry {
  resource_name: string;
  resource_type: ResourceType;
  action: ActionType;
}

function isString(obj: any): obj is string {
  return typeof obj === 'string' || obj instanceof String;
}

function isResourceEntry(obj: any): obj is ResourceEntry {
    return isString(obj.resource_name) && 
      actionTypes.includes(obj.action) && 
      resourceTypes.includes(obj.resource_type);
}


Thank you for this answer, I am still learning the correct terminology and I'm struggling to ask the right questions.

No, you can't. The TypeScript types are only available during compilation, not during the execution (runtime) of your program.
If you are reading data from a source like an HTTP endpoint or a file in the file system, you cannot be sure that the data is what you declare in the types.
You have to write a function that verifies that the contents match what you expect (your types) and then implement any logic. The function is executed after compilation when the types are not available.
There are many ways to do this but here is one exammple:
function validResourrceNameOrThrow(val: string): string {
   if(typeof val === "string" && val !== "") {
    return val;
   } else {
    throw new Error();
  }
}

function validResourrceTypeOrThrow(val: string): ResourceType {
   if (['load_balancer', 'ecs_cluster', 'lambda_function'].includes(val)) {
    return {
      type: val
    } as ResourceType;
  } else {
    throw new Error();
  }
}

function validActionOrThrow(val: string): ActionType {
  if (['REMOVE',  'ADD'].includes(val)) {
    return {
      type: val
    } as ActionType;
  } else {
    throw new Error();
  }
}

declare const csvRows: string[][];

// if this doesn't fail your csv is valid
const verifiedCsv = csvRows.map(cells => {
  return {
      resource_name: validResourrceNameOrThrow(cells[0]),
      resource_type: validResourrceTypeOrThrow(cells[1]),
      action: validActionOrThrow(cells[2])
  } as ResourceEntry;
});

// Here you can turst the types because if tthis is executed is because no error took place earlier
verifiedCsv.forEach(resourceEntry => {
  console.log(resourceEntry.action);
  console.log(resourceEntry.resource_type);
  console.log(resourceEntry.resource_name);
});


An alternative is a type guard like in the other answer by Caleth
